# RESTfully getting HTML partial content via AJAX in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rest, partial-views

In my Rails app, I have a model called "Photo" and a PhotosController. As would be expected, I've RESTfully routed the URLs so that the URL "/photos" returns an HTML-rendered list of all photos (as thumbnails), and "/photos/foo" returns an HTML-rendered representation of the photo with the [friendly_id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) of "foo". (I also do XML, JSON, and binary representations, but they're not relevant here.)

I want to make the list page show a subset of Photo thumbnails on initial load, and then dynamically add more thumbnails to my list via AJAX (specifically jQuery). I already have HTML that renders an individual photo list item (basically an `<li><img>`) in the photos/index view. Since jQuery can [inject HTML directly into the DOM](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load), I figure that the best thing to do is extract the list-item code into a partial and then load that partial through AJAX into the list.

My question is: what's the best way to get the HTML out of the partial and into the DOM?

(I already have an idea for implementation; I'll post it as an answer to allow appropriate voting & commenting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure that the most RESTful way is to make the list-item representation/view of a Photo a sub-resource of the Photo. That would involve:

- Creating a new Photos::ThumbnailsController
- Routing "/photos/:id/thumbnail" to this controller (thus my example URL would be "/photos/foo/thumbnail")
- Creating an index action for this controller (and probably no other actions)
- Having the index action render the partial containing the list item code. (At this point it may make sense to make the partial a full view).
- Make the AJAX call to "/photos/:id/thumbnail" when I wanted to add the thumbnail to the list.

Having a whole other controller/resource for one partial/view does seem like a bit overkill though. Is there a better way?

Comment: Your solutions seems pretty solid and adheres to REST principals. +1

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make it so. The problem is that it seems like a lot of hassle for about 2 HTML tags :-P But I'll go with it if nothing else comes up.

Comment: "Having a whole other controller/resource for one partial/view does seem like a bit overkill" - Agreed, but I've done it that way too for clarity. +1

Comment: That's what I do like about the solution; it's very consistent with both MVC and REST.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a suggestion: check out (view source) how some other players have done the infinite scroll like [Bing's image search](http://www.bing.com/images) or [37 Signals Haystack](http://sortfolio.com/) (which is certainly in Rails as well).

## Results

(edit by Craig)

HayStack makes a call to ["/listings.js"](http://sortfolio.com/listings.js). This means they're probably using a different Rails format in their responds_to call. I considered this, but I don't like it very much because:

- It depends on having a format (js in this case) at the URL that isn't being used for any other purpose (and never will be).
- It depends on JavaScript (and bastardized JS/HTML at that) to do its work. I'd prefer to go pure HTML for consistency, reusability, and cacheability.

Bing's endless search JS was minified so I didn't spend too much time unraveling it.

Comment: This is one of the things I hate about AJAX: trying to figure out in which part of the code the magic happens. :-P